# How to create multiple select box with Zend Framework?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form-element, multipleselection

Zend Framework has Zend_Form_Element_Multiselect element.
But I haven't found any examples how to extend it and create a multiple select box which example is represented here: http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/?whichScript=multiple_select

Maybe someone has done it and could share its own helper or provide an advice how to create multiple select box with Zend Framework  ?
Thank you!

Comment: can you show a demo page which has multiple select box?

Comment: As for example here is an image: http://www.google.lt/imgres?q=html+multiple+select+boxes&hl=ru&sa=X&biw=1920&bih=924&tbm=isch&prmd=imvns&tbnid=AS7yHnuBqE0h_M:&imgrefurl=http://srikanthjeeva.blogspot.com/2009/11/i-have-gone-through-many-examples-for.html&docid=mPfnGn5VhTOFiM&imgurl=http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_WnFS30AIjak/Sw_AeE8FVzI/AAAAAAAABZY/MjYZX6lIUnY/s1600/multiselect.JPG&w=640&h=565&ei=glj4TtbsAuHj4QSvksSNCA&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=493&vpy=150&dur=376&hovh=201&hovw=225&tx=97&ty=100&sig=104473273042932185908&page=1&tbnh=136&tbnw=136&start=0&ndsp=47&ved=1t:429,r:2,s:0

Comment: Doesn't `$elt->setAttrib('multiple', true);` work?

Comment: Yes, it "converts" select element to appropriate. So in order to make it work as in dhtmlgoodies.com example I only should add second the same select element? And push JS separately.

Comment: @Kuzma: Right, I would do it that way: two distinct multi-select elements with separate js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
$this->addElement('MultiCheckbox', 'element-name', array(
                     'label' => 'Multiple Checkboxex',
                    'class'=>'example-class',
                    ));
```